# RecyclerView disable scroll doesnot work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontal scrolling `recyclerview`. The `recyclerviews` child items have slide up panel. So when the panel is expanded i want to block `recyclerview` scrolling.
Till the slide up panel is expanded the user cannot scroll to next item. Once the slide up panel is collapsed then the `recyclerview` scrolling should be enabled.

This is `recyclerview` initialization code

```
 mAdapter = new FootballFeedDetailAdapter(FootballFeedDetailActivity.this);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(footballFeedRecyclerView);
```

I tried using `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

But it is not working

from my adapter if the slideup panel is expanded i am colling the below method

```
public void setUpRecyclerViewScroll(boolean status) {
   footballFeedRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(status);
}
```

Thanks in advance. I will be very helpful if someone answers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend LinearLaoyutManager and override `canScrollHorizontally` method.
When your slideup panel is expanded/collapsed call the layoutmanager `setScrollingEnabled(false/true)`

```
private static class HScrollManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
   private boolean scrollingEnabled = true;

   public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
       scrollingEnabled = enabled;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
       return scrollingEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
   } 
}
```